# Power Set Difference Proof P(A-B)=P(A)-P(B)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I need help proving or disproving this! If anyone could show me the sequence of steps I can use to help me show the left is equal to the right I would be grateful.

$$\mathcal P(A-B)=\mathcal P(A)-\mathcal P(B)$$

Comment: What do you mean by $-$ here? Do you mean the relative complement or the difference of sets?

Comment: It is not true. If $B\subset A$ and $A\neq B$ then $A\in \mathcal{P}(A)-\mathcal{P}(B)$ but $A\notin \mathcal{P}(A-B)$.

Comment: @tetori Unless $B$ is empty.

Comment: @CameronWilliams What's the difference? (No pun intended.)

Comment: They even have the wrong cardinalities. If $B\subset A$, then on the left you have $2^{n-m}$ and on the right you have $2^n-2^m$

Comment: @TrevorWilson It could mean $A-B = \{a-b:a\in A,b\in B\}$. This notation gets used a lot in topological vector space constructs.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Oh, I see.  I didn't realize that's what you meant by "difference of sets".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HINT: $\varnothing\in\wp(A\setminus B)$, $\varnothing\in\wp(A)$, and $\varnothing\in\wp(B)$.